# Unable to use \mathbb{} command

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath

I have recently started using `\Latex`. While typesetting an article, I am facing difficulty in getting the `\mathbb` symbols in the Document title, sections and subsections. How to insert them in title, section and subsections?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\title{Report on study of mappings in \mathbb{C} and matrices in SL(2,\mathbb{R})}
\author{Lionel Ronaldo}
\date{Jan 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\section{Conformal mappings in \mathbb{C}}
\section{Some theorems involving SL(2,\mathbb{R})}}
\subsection{Geometry of analytic functions in \mathbb{C}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\mathbb` is, at the name implies, a math command, so it must be used in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\title{Report on study of mappings in $\mathbb{C}$ and matrices in SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$)}
\author{Lionel Ronaldo}
\date{Jan 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\section{Conformal mappings in $\mathbb{C}$}
\section{Some theorems involving SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$)}
\subsection{Geometry of analytic functions in $\mathbb{C}$}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @VodkaOnTheRockz If this answers your question, please click the Accept button.